# How many elements can perl hash have?

Tags: perl, hash

I was wondering if there is a limit to how many elements Perl hash data structure can hold? I am assuming it is probably dependent on how much memory you have available. Does value and key size matter in terms of how many elements it can hold?

Comment: Do you have a project in mind that you are concerned about?  Are you worried that you might run out of space with 10,000 keys?  10,000,000 keys?

Comment: Ya my data is big 50 billion elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no trivial fixed upper bound.  It depends on the memory available in the system.  If the keys to the hash are bigger, you will run out of memory quicker than if they are smaller.  Similarly with the values in the hash; the bigger they are, the sooner you run out of memory.

Generally, the number of elements that will fit in a hash is the least of your problems; if you run out of memory, you should probably be rethinking your algorithm anyway.

Comment: That makes sense. In Java you have VM limit and your application is bound to that. Since Perl does not have that I am assuming it can eat up most of your RAM if the OS allows it.

Comment: Yes; if the O/S will let it use the memory, Perl will use it (if your program demands it).

Comment: You can go ferreting around the code in Perl's `sv.h`, `hv.h`, and `perl.h`, but you will quickly get confused by the gyrations if you've not studied the code previously.  There is a 32-bit unsigned value storing a hash of the key value, but it seems very unlikely that hash collisions cause problems (and 4 billion distinct keys in the hash will require and awful lot of memory in total, even if the values are only a single byte each).